# Do active predicates and their passive equivalents have different numbers of arguments?

Tags: semantics, predicatives

What are some examples of active predicates in English that have different arguments when rewritten in their passive form?

I guess an active predicate is "He eats the rice" and the passive form is "The rice is eaten by him". In both cases, the predicate seems to have the same semantic arguments, so this is not an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: It depends on the theory you're using to describe sentences with. If you use a generative theory with a Passive rule, generally the rule reduces the number of arguments of a predicate. For instance, in Relational Grammar, Passive is "promote 2 (direct object) to 1 (subject)". The old subject, by rule, is no longer an argument and appears optionally in a _by_ prepositional phrase. So a 2-argument sentence goes to one argument. Of course, it must be a generative grammar of a language with a "passive" rule; not all languages have one, and some have several.

Comment: What John said. 1) The *by*-preposition phrase is sometimes regarded as a complement of the verb, but it fails most syntactic tests for complementhood and so usually isn't. 2) The *by*-preposition phrase is always entirely optional.